# Convert JSON String from mysql db to image

Tags: android, mysql, json, image, android-imageview

I am getting data from an online database and displaying them on my app. I'm getting the data via JSON. I have an image saved as BLOB on the database. I tried using this code to convert the BLOB data to an image and display it on the page, but it doesn't work. (`iv` is an ImageView)

```
String imgstr = intent.getStringExtra("image");
        Log.d("image str from db", "" + imgstr);
        if(imgstr!=null){
            byte[] b = imgstr.getBytes();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }else{
            iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

I have checked all answers related to this on stackoverflow, but doesn't help me. So please don't mark the question as duplicate. Thanks

**UPDATE:** Added how I'm getting the data from the database.`events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

```
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String eid = c.getString(TAG_EID);
                String ename = c.getString(TAG_ENAME);
                String etype = c.getString(TAG_ETYPE);
                String edesc = c.getString(TAG_EDESC);
                String esdate = c.getString(TAG_ESDATE);
                String eedate = c.getString(TAG_EEDATE);
                String estime = c.getString(TAG_ESTIME);
                String eetime = c.getString(TAG_EETIME);
                String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                String created_at = c.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT);
                String edited_at = c.getString(TAG_EDITED_AT);
                String createdby = c.getString(TAG_CREATEDBY);
                String image= c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                String approved = c.getString(TAG_APPROVED);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_EID, eid);
                map.put(TAG_ENAME, ename);
                map.put(TAG_ETYPE, etype);
                map.put(TAG_EDESC, edesc);
                map.put(TAG_ESDATE, esdate);
                map.put(TAG_EEDATE, eedate);
                map.put(TAG_ESTIME, estime);
                map.put(TAG_EETIME, eetime);
                map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                map.put(TAG_CREATED_AT, created_at);
                map.put(TAG_EDITED_AT, edited_at);
                map.put(TAG_CREATEDBY, createdby);
                map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
                map.put(TAG_APPROVED, approved);

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty);
                list.setEmptyView(emptyText);`
```

Then from here when a list item is clicked, the data is passed onto the current intent where I want to display the image

List OnItemClick:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(ListNew.this, NewEvent.class);
                        i.putExtra("eid", oslist.get(+position).get("eid") );
                        //i.putExtra("tel", tels.get(position) );
                        i.putExtra("ename", oslist.get(+position).get("ename") );
                        i.putExtra("etype", oslist.get(+position).get("etype") );
                        i.putExtra("edesc", oslist.get(+position).get("edesc") );
                        i.putExtra("esdate", oslist.get(+position).get("esdate") );
                        i.putExtra("eedate", oslist.get(+position).get("eedate") );
                        i.putExtra("estime", oslist.get(+position).get("estime") );
                        i.putExtra("eetime", oslist.get(+position).get("eetime") );
                        i.putExtra("location", oslist.get(+position).get("location") );
                        i.putExtra("created_at", oslist.get(+position).get("created_at") );
                        i.putExtra("edited_at", oslist.get(+position).get("edited_at") );
                        i.putExtra("createdby", oslist.get(+position).get("createdby") );
                        i.putExtra("image", oslist.get(+position).get("image") );
                        i.putExtra("approved", oslist.get(+position).get("approved") );
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Where you get image from DB? post that  code.

Comment: `getStringExtra("image");`. Should that contain your image? There is no putExtra for it. Please elaborate.

Comment: @greenapps, ah yes, my bad. I added that, still nothing

Comment: `String image= c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);`. Your image is a string? Please elaborate. `String imgstr = intent.getStringExtra("image");`. So you have a string. BitmapFactory cannot make a Bitmap from  a String content. Please elaborate.

Comment: Initially I am getting it as a String, and as I have shown above in the question, I am converting it to a byte array. Then this byte array is what I'm trying to convert to a bitmap @greenapps

Comment: I already saw you doing that. But that will not work as you cannot just put an image in a String. So you should first elaborate on `initially i get it as a string`.

Comment: can you suggest me something to do please? I am all new to this @greenapps

Comment: I would like you to realise how you get an image in a string. You already twice said so. Now elaborate on that. How does one put an image in a String? I don't say it is not possible. I just want you to realise and explain us how that can be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77957/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-greenapps).

Comment: No. You should realise that the image is saved as blob data in the database  on the server. But you get it to your device in a json text. Json texts do not contain blob data. Please rethink/find out how on server side the image is put in the json response and how your android code receives it.